# Images in fluid layout do not return to original width (webkit only)

Tags: css, image, webkit, fluid

My website is responsive. It works great except for the images in the portfolio section. When the page first loads they appear as they should, when you shrink the browser window everything behaves properly. However when you widen the browser back to the original width (assuming you started on a desktop with a "normal" browser window width) the images do not increase in size related to their parent container's width.

URL:
http://designintellection.com/portfolio/

Here's the relevant CSS:
http://pastebin.com/7YvQD4Hp

This only happens with Safari and Chrome. Works fine on Firefox and Opera.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome and the iPhone image is shrinking and growing just fine on Windows 7.  Safari 5.1.2 is also behaving properly.  I'm not seeing the issue.

Comment: I tested Chrome, Safari and Firefox on a mac and everything is behaving normally... not sure what the bug is.

Comment: Oh, well I guess that's good to hear. My issue is in Safari 5.1.2/Chrome 17 on a Mac. I'll wait for a few more days and close the ticket if no one else is seeing it. Here's what mine looks like: https://img.skitch.com/20120301-xk9422f4455wywg7i978hxs5f3.jpg

Comment: using safari 5.1.2 and chrome 17.0.963.56 on mac and all is well and good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issue in Chrome.  I believe it's being caused by a float:left that you have on .pf-screen:

.pf-screen { margin-left:2.093%; /*18/860*/ **float:left;** }

For the images that are 100% width, if you remove the float on their container element(.pf-screen), it fixes the issue in Chrome.